# Fluid particles offset

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to create a small creek for an animation and want the water to offset to a start point where the creek is full of water, to do that I have used the offset option of the fluid domain so that the start frame goes 500 frames ahead.

My problem is that the fluid particles I have created for the small water jumps and their foam, drops, tracers doesn't follow that offset and start from the beginning of the animation. On the particles settings I don't have an offset as the non fluid particles would have.

Is there any way to match the particles offset to the one of the fluid animation other than creating the animation from the beginning and skip to frame 500?